# How to align but with offset

Tags: c, gcc, arm, alignment, c11

Say I need to allocate `struct A` but `b` needs to be 4 aligned.

```
struct A
{
    char a;
    char b[42];
};
```

I guess I can manually pad a pointer returned by `malloc()`. Any cleaner way? Like gcc's `__attribute__((aligned(4)))` but that aligns the whole structure. And I can't change it's layout.

Comment: in general the compiler chooses and not the language (compiler specific), so you have to tune your code to the toolchain and version.   I assume you are trying to use structs across compile domains and in general that is a very bad idea, so should back up and solve this in a more reliable way (not with structs).  and certainly if you want to use malloc then also need to pad and adjust the output from malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alignas(<alignment>)` on the structure member you want to align. This implies that `struct` and `union` types will get an alignment equal to the largest alignment of any member, and will insert padding between elements (and array entries) to ensure that the necessary alignment is provided.

For compiler-allocated data (static or stack) this is all you need to do.

For C11, for any dynamically allocated data you still need to ensure that the base pointer of the allocation is suitably aligned - malloc doesn't guarantee much more than "enough for the longest native type". In your case with `alignas(4)` malloc would likely fit in the longest native type so malloc would be OK, but in the general case you might need manually calculated padding if over-aligning (e.g. for SIMD vector loads).

If you want standard support for this you need to fast-forward to C++17, which adds a number of memory allocators that take alignment as a parameter. These allocators are used specifically for over-aligned types. Also C++17 guarantees any allocations from `new` are sufficiently aligned for `alignof(std::max_align_t)` by default.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "you still need to ensure that the base pointer of the allocation is suitably aligned - malloc doesn't guarantee this". malloc guarantees (C17 7.22.3) that: `"The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)."` This text was changed slightly from C11 but I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: For align 4 you would be OK - on nearly all systems that's smaller than the largest native type so malloc should be OK. You would hit problems if you want alignment that is larger than alignof(std::max_align_t) - e.g. over-aligning for SIMD aligned loads - on many systems malloc only guarantees 8 byte alignment (if 64-bit = longest native type).

Answer (score 1):

With standard C you can use the keyword `_Alignas` (or the macro `alignas` from `stdalign.h`):

```c
struct A
{
  _Alignas(4) char a;
  _Alignas(4) char b[42];
};
```

This consequently makes `a` occupy 4 bytes and `b` 44 bytes. Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct A
{
  char a;
  char b[42];
};

struct B
{
  _Alignas(4) char a;
  _Alignas(4) char b[42];
};

int main (void)
{
  printf("Size A: %zu\n", sizeof(struct A));
  printf("Offset A.a: %zu\n", offsetof(struct A,a));
  printf("Offset A.b: %zu\n", offsetof(struct A,b));

  printf("Size B: %zu\n", sizeof(struct B));
  printf("Offset B.a: %zu\n", offsetof(struct B,a));
  printf("Offset B.b: %zu\n", offsetof(struct B,b));
}
```

Output:

```
Size A: 43
Offset A.a: 0
Offset A.b: 1
Size B: 48
Offset B.a: 0
Offset B.b: 4
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank You! One goofy question - why the "as" in `_Alignas`?

Comment: @Vorac I assume it's because you may as well use a type as input, as an integer constant. Example: `_Alignas(int)`, "align as if was an int".